# how to clear ckeditor with jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

How can i clear the ckeditor textarea with jquery at the click of a button/link?

I have tried this : `$("textarea.editor").val('');` and `$("textarea.editor1").val('');` i tried with the 1 at the end because of this line when init the editor `$ckeditor->editor('editor1', $nDetails);` in PHP

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<p>Details: 

    <?php

    // Helper function for this sample file.
    function printNotFound( $ver )
    {
        static $warned;

        if (!empty($warned))
            return;

        echo '<p><br><strong><span class="error">Error</span>: '.$ver.' not found</strong>. ' .
            'This sample assumes that '.$ver.' (not included with CKFinder) is installed in ' .
            'the "ckeditor" sibling folder of the CKFinder installation folder. If you have it installed in ' .
            'a different place, just edit this file, changing the wrong paths in the include ' .
            '(line 57) and the "basePath" values (line 70).</p>' ;
        $warned = true;
    }



    include_once '../ckeditor/ckeditor.php' ;
    require_once '../ckfinder/ckfinder.php' ;

    // This is a check for the CKEditor class. If not defined, the paths in lines 57 and 70 must be checked.
    if (!class_exists('CKEditor'))
    {
        printNotFound('CKEditor');
    }
    else
    {
        $initialValue = $pageContent;

        $ckeditor = new CKEditor( ) ;
        $ckeditor->basePath = '../ckeditor/' ;

        // Just call CKFinder::SetupCKEditor before calling editor(), replace() or replaceAll()
        // in CKEditor. The second parameter (optional), is the path for the
        // CKFinder installation (default = "/ckfinder/").
        CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $ckeditor, '/ckfinder/' ) ;

        $ckeditor->editor('editor1', $nDetails);
    }

    ?></p>
```

Comment: Does the editor have a <div> or some container it holds the text in?  Could you show the HTML of the editor control?

Comment: see edit above.  I have it in a p tag,  also have a few form fields in a form but and the form sits in a div.

Comment: I tried to use the demo (http://ckeditor.com/demo) and firebug to write some jQuery, but had no luck ... sorry.

Answer (score 62):

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('');`

Where editor1 is the id of your CKEDITOR field

Comment: It works in IE for me (no errors in the javascript console either). Version: 9.0.8112.16421 64-bit Edition, Update Versions: 9.0.10

Comment: This works for me in Chrome in CKEditor version 4.2.3 standard. Thanks.

Comment: `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(''); ` this clear the content OK, but when a call `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('some content');` it dont insert nothing anymore inside the cleared box...

Comment: [SOLVED] `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('some html content');` instead `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('');`

Comment: can you write the complete solution? How do you get the id of the CKEditor field?

Answer (score 19):

The below code clears the value in the ckeditor textarea. This will works 4.4 version also.

```
      CKEDITOR.instances['content'].setData('');
```

Content is the id of the particular text-area.

Answer (score 2):

Try it may helpful.

```
function CKupdate(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');
}   

$.ajax({
   url: $('#CommunicationForm').attr("action"),
   type: $('#CommunicationForm').attr("method"),
   data: $('#CommunicationForm').serialize(),
   success: function (e) {
       if (e.error) {
          alert(e.error);
       } else {
          //Doing Clear here                          
          CKupdate();
       }
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, Status, text) {
        alert("error! " + text);
   }   
});
```

Call `CKupdate()` function when when you want to clear CKEditor text.

Comment: works great thank you, I already used the updateElement() at the top of my function anyway so I just added the setData('') part within the .done() callback :)

Comment: worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to clear CK Editor Data

```
CKEDITOR.instances['yourCKeditorID'].setData('');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code i had to change the text in the ckeditor programmatically but it did not work until i did a defered set. This may be helpful.

```
_.defer(function () {
    it._controls.wysiwyg.setData(bodyText); // by the direct reference
    //CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(''); // or this way like in the example
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
        $(".ck-blurred p").html("") //empty ckeditor
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.